# Mutually dependant signals

Tags: elm

*Bare question:*

Is there a way of defining a pair of signals that depend on each other in Elm?

*Preamble:*

I'm trying to write a tiny Cookie-clicker-style browser game in which the player is gathering resources, then spending them to purchase autonomous resource-gathering constructs which get more expensive as they're purchased. That implies three relevant signals: `gathered` (how much resources the player has gathered), `spent` (how much resource the player has already spent) and `cost` (how much an upgrade costs).

Here's an implementation:

```
module Test where

import Mouse
import Time

port gather : Signal Bool
port build : Signal String

costIncrement = constant 50
cost = foldp (+) 0 <| keepWhen canAfford 0 <| sampleOn build costIncrement
nextCost = lift2 (+) cost costIncrement

spent = foldp (+) 0 <| merges [ sampleOn build cost ]

gathered = foldp (+) 0 <| merges [ sampleOn gather <| constant 1, sampleOn tick tickIncrement ]

balance = lift round <| lift2 (-) gathered spent

canAfford = lift2 (>) balance <| lift round nextCost

tickIncrement = foldp (+) 0 <| sampleOn cost <| constant 0.01
tick = sampleOn (every Time.millisecond) <| constant True

main = lift (flow down) <| combine [ lift asText balance, lift asText canAfford, lift asText spent, lift asText gathered, lift asText nextCost ]
```

This compiles fine, but when I embed it in an HTML file with the appropriate buttons hooked up to send messages to the appropriate ports above, I get the error

```
s2 is undefined
    Open the developer console for more details.
```

The problem seems to be that as written, `cost` depends on `canAfford`, which depends on `balance`, which depends on `spent`, which depends on `cost` again.

If I modify the cost line such that

```
...
cost = foldp (+) 0 <| sampleOn build costIncrement
...
```

it starts working as expected (except that the player is allowed to spend into negative resources, which is what I'd like to avoid).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Answer to your bare question

**No**, there is no general way in Elm to define mutually recursive signals.
The problem lies in the constraint that a `Signal` in Elm must always have a value. If the definition of `cost` requires `canAfford` but `canAfford` is defined in terms of `cost`, the problem is where to start with resolving the initial value of the signal. This is a tough problem to solve when you think in terms of mutually recursive signals.

Mutually recursive signals have everything to do with past values of signals. The `foldp` construct allows you to specify the equivalent of mutually recursive signals up to a point. The solution to the initial value problem is solved by having an explicit argument to `foldp` that is the initial value. But the constraint is that `foldp` only takes pure functions.

This problem is hard to clearly explain in a way that doesn't require any prior knowledge. So here's another explanation, based on a diagram I made of your code.

[image: signal graph of the code given by the OP]

Take your time to find the connections between the code and the diagram (note that I left out `main` to simplify the graph). A `foldp` is a node with a loop back, `sampleOn` has a lightning bolt etc. (I rewrote `sampleOn` on a constant signal to `always`). The problematic part is the red line going up, using `canAfford` in the definition of `cost`.
As you can see, a basic `foldp` has a simple loop with a base value. Implementing this is easier than arbitrary loop-back like yours.

I hope you understand the problem now. The limitation is in Elm, it's not your fault.
I'm resolving this limitation in Elm although it will take some time to do so.

## Solution to your problem

Although it can be nice to name signals and work with those, when implementing games in Elm it usually helps to use a [different programming style](http://elm-lang.org/blog/Pong.elm). The idea in the linked article comes down to splitting your code up in:

1. Inputs: `Mouse`, `Time` and ports in your case.
2. Model: The state of the game, in your case `cost`, `balance`, `canAfford`, `spent`, `gathered` etc.
3. Update: The update function of the game, you can compose these out of smaller update functions. These should be *pure* functions as much as possible.
4. View: Code to view the model.

Tie it all together by using something like `main = view <~ foldp update modelStartValues inputs`.

In particular, I would write it like:

```
import Mouse
import Time

-- Constants
costInc      = 50
tickIncStep  = 0.01
gatherAmount = 1

-- Inputs
port gather : Signal Bool
port build : Signal String

tick = (always True) <~ (every Time.millisecond)

data Input = Build String | Gather Bool | Tick Bool

inputs = merges [ Build  <~ build
                , Gather <~ gather
                , Tick   <~ tick
                ]

-- Model

type GameState = { cost          : Float
                 , spent         : Float
                 , gathered      : Float
                 , tickIncrement : Float
                 }

gameState = GameState 0 0 0 0

-- Update

balance {gathered, spent} = round (gathered - spent)
nextCost {cost} = cost + costInc
canAfford gameSt = balance gameSt > round (nextCost gameSt)

newCost input gameSt =
  case input of
    Build _ -> 
      if canAfford gameSt
        then gameSt.cost + costInc
        else gameSt.cost
    _ -> gameSt.cost

newSpent input {spent, cost} = 
  case input of
    Build _ -> spent + cost
    _ -> spent

newGathered input {gathered, tickIncrement} = 
  case input of
    Gather _ -> gathered + gatherAmount
    Tick   _ -> gathered + tickIncrement
    _ -> gathered

newTickIncrement input {tickIncrement} =
  case input of
    Tick _ -> tickIncrement + tickIncStep
    _ -> tickIncrement

update input gameSt = GameState (newCost          input gameSt)
                                (newSpent         input gameSt)
                                (newGathered      input gameSt)
                                (newTickIncrement input gameSt)

-- View
view gameSt = 
  flow down <| 
    map ((|>) gameSt)
      [ asText . balance
      , asText . canAfford
      , asText . .spent
      , asText . .gathered
      , asText . nextCost ]

-- Main

main = view <~ foldp update gameState inputs
```

Comment: How are you resolving the signal of signal type limitation?

Comment: @CMCDragonKai Do you mean how I'm planning to solve the general limitation in Elm? Or just how the code in my post works around the problem of the OP?

Comment: In general, I'm curious! Kafka/Eventsourcing also has this problem.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Most recent discussion on the mailing list is here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-discuss/AQpYNAO5Y8g/pcKgx7vqz9gJ. Older discussions use the name "signal loop" for the feature I'm developing. But those are discussions on how it should work, not clear explanations on how it will work.

Comment: @AdrianoFerrari I built the graph by hand (in Dia) using symbols from [Evans thesis on elm](http://elm-lang.org/papers/concurrent-frp.pdf) (section 4.1), and [symbols I proposed myself on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-discuss/mDhgg1cbX4M/n6pcjwunEsAJ).