# Cannot read property 'kids' of undefined - or how to break a circular dependency of signals in Elm?

Tags: elm, elm-signal

While `elm-make` succeeds, I get the following error in the browser:

> Cannot read property 'kids' of undefined

I assume it's because I have a circular dependency of signals:

```
model -> clicks -> model
```

Here is the relevant code:

```elm
model : Signal Model
model =
  Signal.foldp update initialModel clicks


clicks : Signal Action
clicks =
  let
    clickPosition = Mouse.position
      |> Signal.sampleOn Mouse.clicks
    tuplesSignal = Signal.map3 (,,) clickPosition Window.dimensions model      
  in
    ...
```

It feels like `model` is implemented as a common practice in Elm, so I should challenge the `clicks -> model` dependency.

Here is some context:

I'm building a sliding puzzle game using canvas:

[image]

When user clicks a tile that can move, it should move. Otherwise, the click should be ignored.

`clicks` will produce the following actions: `Left`, `Right`, `Up`, `Down`

For example, if user clicks on tiles 12, 11, 8, 15 (in this order), `clicks` should be: `Down -> Right -> Up`

The problem is, that in order to calculate which tile was clicked, I need to know the board dimensions (e.g. 4 rows and 4 columns in the picture above). But, board dimensions are stored in the `model` (imagine user interface that allows users to change board dimensions).

How do I get out of this circular dependency?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22261359/859279

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I think you should go more low-level in what you call an input, and accept click positions as inputs. Then you can compose an `update` function in your `Signal.foldp` out of two others:

1. The first turns the clicks and model into a `Maybe Direction` (assuming the `Left`, `Right`, `Up`, `Down` are constructors of type `Direction`)
2. The second function that takes a `Direction` value and the model to calculate the new model. You can use `Maybe.map` and `Maybe.withDefault` to handle the `Maybe` part of the result of the first function.

Separating these two parts, even though you produce and consume `Direction` immediately, makes your system more self-documenting and shows the conceptual split between the raw input and the restricted "actual" inputs.

P.S. There are [conceivable extensions](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elm-discuss/AQpYNAO5Y8g/discussion) to the Elm language that would allow you to more easily write this input preprocessing in signal-land. But such extensions would make the signal part of the language so much more powerful that it's unclear if it would make "the right way" to structure programs harder to discover.